# Android: Error code 2 when trying to run android project

Tags: android, android-studio

Projects builds with 4 warnings but when I try to run it I get error with code 2, unexpected top-level exception.

Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
    compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the exception, i.e. exception class, stack trace.

Comment: It could be that you have one too many `}` in your file? Try following the `{` and `}` after `buildTypes`... or you're only showing part of the `build.gradle` file?